# Choose (or create) ads to display in AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads

In my `Android` app I want to display specific ads that already exist or I would create.

`Banner Ads` should be of restaurants / bars in my area, which are agreed with the owners of the premises. So I need to display existing `Ads` or create them as "House Ads".

It is possible by `AdMob`? Obviously I can display images or something else within the app, but I want safety and trace-ability of `AdMob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Simply add the AdMob SDK like you normally would, then go to the AdMob website console, and set a really high ECM value for the AdMob network so that no "regular" ads are shown (or set it to "only show ads from Greece in Norwegian" to effectively disable AdMob ads). Then, setup your house ads in the "Campaigns" tab in AdMob.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!